# NHibernate Fluent and named Queries

Tags: nhibernate, fluent, named-query

I am using Nhibernate with fluent.
Now I want to call some Stored procedure and use named Queries.
I created some xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping>
  <sql-query name="CleanAppendicesHierarchies">
    exec intf_CleanUpAppendixHierarchy
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

```
    FluentConfiguration cfg =
    Fluently.Configure().Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(
c => c.Is(dbConnectionString)).ShowSql())
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(mappingAssembly))
.Mappings(m => m.HbmMappings.AddFromAssembly(mappingAssembly));
```

Now I got always the Exception:(most inner exception)
{"hibernate-mapping xmlns='' was not expected."} {"There is an error in XML document (1, 2)."}

I fiddled around but if I remove hibernate-mapping then it complains about the sql-query tag.

What is wrong in my approach? I googled already found examples but of course with out Fluent....

Any hint is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange, I got it working with that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="FactsheetsDataLayer"
                   namespace="FactsheetsDataLayer">  
  <sql-query name="CleanAppendicesHierarchies">
    exec intf_CleanUpAppendixHierarchy
  </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Then I named the XMl like: POCOClassName.hbm.xml

I do not know what helped but now it worked....

Comment: Obviously the namespace declaration must not be empty in .hbm files. That's why at first you got an exception saying `{"hibernate-mapping xmlns='' was not expected."}` but when you put `xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"` in there NHibernate was satisfied.