# Fluent Nhibernate and hbms

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

As an FNH user, do you find you sometimes need to supplement FNH with an hbm file? Any relatively common edge cases where you do, if so?

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When a bug in Fluent NHibernate prohibits something. There are less bugs each release, but you might find some eventually (the most recent is the inability to map dictionaries when certain auto mapping conventions exist)
2. When you have a legacy system (mapped using hbms) for which you need to add new domain objects (mapped using fnh and/or automapping).

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use named queries you will need to use an hbm file and you would probably use a named query to call a stored procedure whether this be because you have legacy stored procs to call, possibly performance or in my most recent case, to do a full text search. More info on setting this up can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613904/nhibernate-fluent-and-named-queries) and [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/23/populating-entities-from-stored-procedures-with-nhibernate.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FNH Automapping on my (so far, one and only) NHibernate project.

At first, I had to write a couple of FNH overrides to work around bugs.  But the bugs were quickly fixed by the FNH team, and I was able to eliminate the overrides completely.

Never had to deal with the HBM files, and I hope it stays that way!